# How to set Bootstrap Make-Switch with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the bootstrap switches to change a check box into a toggle box. When the page loads the switch is in the data-off position being red and text saying no.

```
<div class="make-switch" id="use_map_switch" data-on-label="Yes" data-off-label="No" data-on="success" data-off="danger">
    <input type="checkbox" name="use_map" id="use_map" value="1" {if $form_data.use_map eq 1}checked{/if} />
</div>
```

I run a jQuery script once the check/switch is clicked and changed to yes/green. If the results turn back false I want to change the switch/check back to No/red.

I have tried using the line $('#use_map').prop('checked', false); but this has had no affect.

```
$('#use_map_switch label').click(function(){
    // need to do opposite
    // if its checked when clicked then switch will be going to unchecked
    if($('#use_map').is(':checked')){
        $('.map-area').hide();
    } else {
        address = getAddress();
        if(address == ''){
            modalTitle = 'Error';
            modalText = 'Please enter an address before using the map';
            $('#use_map').prop('checked', false);
            show_modal(modalTitle, modalText);
        } else {
            $('.map-area').show();
            $('.map-area').html(address);
        }
    }
});
```